Automatically run a program whenever a second program is launched
Is there a way to make sure that evertime processA starts, processB is also started?
Something like this:
if (program == r6)
   start "r6tracker.exe"

I don't want to create a resource consuming looping script. I have tried with task scheduler, but don't know how to create a trigger for when processA is launched.

You could try just placing
START processB.bat

At the start of the script from processA, this will automaticly start processB when processA is started.
change the name: processB.bat to the name of your program.
